# How to handle missing columns when processing flexible-schema json in scala spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Using spark streaming to read from kafka  messages where V = Json event.

The Json's schema isn't enforced, so you might fetch the following 2 events:

```
{"foo": "01/01/1973","bar": "d,e"}
{"foo": "01/01/1974"}
```

using `read.json` and `df.registerTempTable("tempTable")`
How do I create a `query = "select foo, bar from tempTable"` that plugs a NULL in case the field doesn't exist?

*Using spark 1.6, but would be also happy to hear about spark2

Comment: You can create a CustomSchema for generating NULLs when field is not exist.

Answer (score 1):

In order to handle null values, you could use [na functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions). It's available in Spark 1.6. For instance, in your case you can use the fill function, which replaces null or non-existent values with a default value, once you have created the Dataframe by reading the json file:

```
df.na.fill("NULL", Seq("bar")).registerTempTable("tempTable")
```

The first argument is the default value, and the second one is a Seq or an Array object with the column names to fill.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks I'm looking at it now.  Just a quick note, looks like for me it is expecting me to use a more qualified call (specifically typing "na"): `df.na.fill("NULL", Seq("bar")).registerTempTable("tempTable")`

Answer (score 1):

If you can use spark 2.x, you don't need to care about handling null values example:

```
spark.read.json("test.json").registerTempTable("tempTable")
spark.sql("select foo, bar from tempTable")
```

output:

```
+----------+----+
|       foo| bar|
+----------+----+
|01/01/1973| d,e|
|01/01/1974|null|
+----------+----+
```